# Cordova zip plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, zip, unzip

I am trying to use cordova zip plugin .I have created a simple cordova project ,added android platform and plugins.Inside index.html, I have simple code as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Zip Plugin to extract files</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Zip Plugin to extract files</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
            $('#zipfile').click(function(e) {
                zip.unzip("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zHrNsznc9BUXBVTUE0OE9vY0E/view?ts=569cbb1c", "http://www.google.com", 
                    function(){
                         console.log('Zip decompressed successfully');
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
         <button type="file" id="zipfile" name="zipFile"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem : I am not able to invoke the click event handler;also I am sceptical about the code that I have written for unzipping. Please let me know if I am missing any mandatory methods in order to make use of zip plugin.
I am trying in latest cordova version in Android-23 sdk(win7 machine).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a link to the Zip plugin that you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip here is the link that I am using to try this feature.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, the second argument to unzip is the destination. You used google.com as a destination, which doesn't make sense. You want to use a local path instead.